# How to create unkillable python script?

Tags: python, cron, terminate, rights

My alarm clock is a python script that's triggered with Cron. It plays music for an hour using `pygame`, gradually increasing the volume.

Recently, a weak-willed, semi-conscious version of myself has learned how to turn off the script using `pkill -f alarm.py`.

Is there a way I configure my Python script or Cron task to prevent it from being terminated with `pkill`?

Comment: run script as `root` and don't give your "semi-conscious" user permissions to kill it ?

Comment: You are the epitome of a developer. Creative enough to build something, but lazy enough to pkill it.

Comment: @Vor I can't think of a single dev who isn't the very most admin of their personal computer though, so root access might be out simply because of how we configure our lives (full control)

Comment: The only problem I see here OP, is simply that it's a function of an alarm to turn off. If you disable it, you have music for an hour that you potentially can't kill. That can get annoying especially if you're being murdered at the time and silence is of the essence. This question may come down to you moving your computer off your bed (let's be honest, I sleep with my computer too) or trading in your willpower for more power

Comment: For every solution you will make, you will just find a way to stop/snooze the alarm. Get rid of the alarm altogether before your desktop jumps out the window.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is probably a little intense for most people's purposes, but here's what I ended up doing.

I'm running Linux and **warning:** this makes the Python process unkillable by disabling the keyboard for the duration of the script.

```
import time, subprocess

keyboard_id   = 11 # find this by running "xinput -list"

# disable the keyboard
subprocess.call(["xinput", "set-prop", str(keyboard_id), "Device Enabled", "0"])

# ... do alarm stuff for a while ... #
time.sleep(10)

# re-enable keyboard after alarm finishes
subprocess.call(["xinput", "set-prop", str(keyboard_id), "Device Enabled", "1"])
pass
```

Checkmate, future me.